# Update to MySQL

Tags: php

I`m stuck again with this script, i am now trying to update an existing client in table "wdclient" but no update goes though to the database.

Trying to insert "products" and "description".

Here is my code:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$clientId=$_GET['clientId'];
include ('msql_connect.php');
include ('msql_open.php');
include ('header.php'); 

    $base1 = '<option value="';
    $base2 = '">';
    $base3 = '</option>';

     if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

mysql_query("UPDATE wdclient (cdetail, cproducts) WHERE clid = '$clientId'
VALUES ('$_POST[detail]', '$_POST[products]')");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO wdccat (caid, clid) VALUES ('$_POST[category1]','$_POST[clid]')");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO wdccat (caid, clid) VALUES ('$_POST[category2]','$_POST[clid]')");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO wdccat (caid, clid) VALUES ('$_POST[category3]','$_POST[clid]')");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO wdccat (caid, clid) VALUES ('$_POST[category4]','$_POST[clid]')");
     }

?>
    <div class="tagline"> 
        <h1>Finish your Registration!</h1> 
        <span><em>Complete your Registration!</em></span>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div> 
    <div class="wrapper">                       
                    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="contactform" class="big_form" >    
    <div id="section1"> 
    <?php 
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM wdcat ORDER BY `ccname` ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);

    while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    }
    ?> 
<table width="1000" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th width="185" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col"><h2 >Choose up to 4 Categories:</h2></th>
    <th width="30" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="308"><label for="text"><b style="color:#C00">*</b> Select Category:</label><select name="category1" id="category1" value="" class="required"><?php $SQL = "SELECT * FROM wdcat ORDER BY `ccname` ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);

    while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo $base1;
    print $db_field['ccid'];
    echo $base2;
    print $db_field['ccname'];
    echo $base3;

    };?></select></td>
    <td width="459"><label for="text"><b style="color:#C00">*</b> Select Category:</label><select name="category2" id="category2" value="" class="required"><?php $SQL = "SELECT * FROM wdcat ORDER BY `ccname` ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);

    while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo $base1;
    print $db_field['ccid'];
    echo $base2;
    print $db_field['ccname'];
    echo $base3;

    };?></select></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><label for="text"><b style="color:#C00">*</b> Select Category:</label><select name="category3" id="category3" value="" class="required"><?php $SQL = "SELECT * FROM wdcat ORDER BY `ccname` ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);

    while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo $base1;
    print $db_field['ccid'];
    echo $base2;
    print $db_field['ccname'];
    echo $base3;

    };?></select></td>
    <td><label for="text"><b style="color:#C00">*</b> Select Category:</label><select name="category4" id="category4" value="" class="required"><?php $SQL = "SELECT * FROM wdcat ORDER BY `ccname` ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);

    while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo $base1;
    print $db_field['ccid'];
    echo $base2;
    print $db_field['ccname'];
    echo $base3;

    };?></select></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2"><br/>
    <h2>Company Information:</h2></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><label for="description"><b style="color:#C00">* </b>Company Description:</label>
    <textarea name="detail" id="detail" cols="40" rows="8"></textarea></td>
    <td><label for="description"><b style="color:#C00">* </b>Products: (eg, shoes, bedding, tableware)</label>
    <textarea name="products" id="products" cols="40" rows="8"></textarea></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2"><br/>
    <h2>Upload Images:</h2><br/></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="clid" id="clid" value="<?php echo $clientId ;?>"></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Complete Registration" name="submit" class="button form" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>

            <div class="clear"></div>                   
</div>
</div>
<?php include ('msql_close.php'); ?>
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

Any assistance will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What happens / does not happen?

Comment: Hint: Read UPDATE syntax http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html

Answer (score 6):

Looks like your syntax is off

```
mysql_query("UPDATE wdclient (cdetail, cproducts) WHERE clid = '$clientId'
VALUES ('$_POST[detail]', '$_POST[products]')");
```

should be

```
mysql_query("UPDATE wdclient set cdetail='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[detail])."', cproducts='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[products])."' WHERE clid = '$clientId'
```

Notice that you should always use mysql_real_escape_string or ensure that data is safe via other means. Same goes for your insert statements.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE wdclient set cdetail = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[detail])."' , cproducts = '".
     mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[products])."'  WHERE clid = ".mysql_real_escape_string($clientId));
```

Comment: Did you really just put unsanitized user input into a SQL query?  Edit:  Ok, I see the OP did too, but don't encourage him!

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
mysql_query($your_query) or die(mysql_error());
```

to see if there are errors while executing your queries

Comment: It's obvious what his error is. The syntax of his UPDATE function is not valid.

Comment: +1. The completely-wrong UPDATE syntax is not the real problem; the real problem is that the code doesn't check for errors. The broken SQL statement is a natural consequence of that. (Everyone introduces syntax errors occasionally. You can't completely prevent them, you can only make sure that you can identify and fix them when they occur.)

Comment: @ruakh - Agreed, however he is asking why it's not working and the reason is because of the invalid syntax. That is the real problem. Of course he should be checking for errors.

Comment: Ok, I suggested the above to help him also in the future.

Comment: @Flukey: You say "of course", but obviously the OP didn't realize this, and Khronos's is the only answer that pointed it out. Once that issue is addressed, the OP has a fighting chance to solve his own UPDATE syntax problems. (Teach a man to fish.)

Comment: @Flukey No problem if you were ;)